# tool to accomplish complex email sending in PHP ( possibly in Yii )

Tags: php, email, yii

Here is the task:

- Send email to a group of users
- Set limit to the number of emails sent per hour
- Track the progress

and things like that.

What is a good library or anything else to do this?

I am trying to do all that in YII framework, so advice on a good extension would be much appreciated!

Comment: MailChimp or similar email service

Comment: I need to do that in PHP

Comment: Many pitfalls with this, including: mail being marked as spam; mailserver being blacklisted; formatting between app and web mail clients etc. Something like MailChimp or CampaignMonitor would save you a lot of pain.

Comment: @Ruskin I wish I could. the requirement is to use PHP, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a framework like Drupal then start with http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mail.php

For tracking, be worth using a url shortener to track link clicks - or the classic hidden image method for mail viewings, though that does not work on Gmail now (it auto downloads all images when it gets images - bad data) or if people have images switched off.

Educate your superiors on what is possible and limitiations. Can you make a case to use another technology? I find if you plant a seed idea it may fruit in 3-8 weeks.

Comment: I am using Yii! I know about mail() function and used it. basically, it sends email to emails provided to foreach loop in my case. The problem is putting limit to the number of emails sent per hour and tracking how many of emails are sent and not sent